# Getting these images to span full-width of the boxes

Tags: css, image

I have been working at this for like 3 hours and everything I try in Google Chrome doesn't fix it, nor sizing the images to massive width/height.

Basically, I would like to get rid of that whitespace around the 3 images under "featured products." I want all the images to span those widths (big one is like 66.66 and the two smaller ones are 33.33%). No amount of resizing the images or changing the code is working, so I must be missing something.

The password to get in is "fusrodraw"

http://shop.thewiredlife.net/

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using img tags, assign them as background images to the anchors and then use background-size: cover

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.grid-product__image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Take the max-width and max-height out of the equation

Comment: Glad to be of help @KelseyKronmiller :)